PrimeVue Installation Issue: Missing Resources Folder ( node_modules/primevue/resources )
I'm experiencing an issue installing PrimeVue. After running npm install, the resources folder (node_modules/primevue/resources) is missing. Only this specific project fails to install PrimeVue's resources folder. This prevents me from accessing PrimeVue's CSS themes.
List of steps I've taken:
Installed PrimeVue via npm install primevue@latest.
Verified primevue in package.json.
Cleared npm/yarn cache and reinstalled.
Checked PrimeVue version compatibility.
enter image description here

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

In the latest version, the resources folder has been removed.
source: https://primevue.org/guides/migration/v4/

Ohh. Thank for the reply.
